# Book series about an orphan named Colin who fights demons for a council of mages

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

It was a book about a male lead young adult.
It started off at a school and I believe his name was Colin but I could be wrong.
He is a mage or has powers.
He goes to a academy of sorts and learns to be a mage but also he tries to be a fighter at the same time.
It has demons or aliens maybe a cross of with otherdimensional demons. 
He is adopted and at the end of the first book when they are having a large scale fight he almost dies.
I read this around 2-3 years ago from Kindle for free.
At the end there is a council of mages where he girlfriend kills them  due to them not sending reinforcements when they were fighting demons which resulted in the main character almost suiciding and going into a sort of magic coma.
Four books in this series, first book is about the academy of magic where he is clever and creates a lot of spells and improves on others, in this book he also goes onto a mission and goes to another state.
Has a girlfriend who he was friends with in the first book but get together in the second, she almost dies when humans who are working with the demons try to kill her but the main character saves her , he jumps out of a plane and kills them. Demons turn up and he lets them go.
His mother was killed when demons invaded and father goes mad and kills a full nest. 
Main character has some demon blood.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Does the council get killed by his girlfriend? Or the council lies to her?

Comment: She kills them due to them not sending reinforcements when they were fighting demons which resulted in the main character almost suiciding and going into a sort of magic coma

Comment: That's a good detail. Do you know how many books were in the series approximately? You mention this was the first book.

Comment: I believe four. 
The first one was where they society of mages is hidden but due to the demons invading they pretty much become known to the world at the end. Second is when they have come out to humans and try to work together to avoid invasion. The third is when the war is really kicking off and he travels to the other dimensions. The fourth it about a side character who was one of his friends who he thought was killed in book two.

Comment: Did it perhaps start with a Babylonian demon ripping itself out of a pregnant woman's belly?

Comment: From what i can remember no. I could be wrong as the main characters mother died during childbirth snd the main character has some demon blood. The mother was killed due to demons. The father went mad and pretty much killed a full nest of demons.

Comment: All this stuff needs to be edited into the question.

Comment: :) It sounds like you have a lot of details that haven't made it into the question...

Comment: Honestly, you guys are sort of making me remember this stuff thanks xD

Comment: Just to check, have you gone through the checklist we gave you? It's another good way to prompt for memories.

Comment: Yes i can remember the book details but the actual book titles i cant remember :/

Answer (score 5):

You're describing the [Soulguard](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28638334-soulguard) series of books by Christopher Woods.
I read it about five years ago and re-read it last year. There are five books in the series.

Some of your details are a little fuzzy, but you got his name right; Colin Rourke is an orphan whose mother was attacked by these demons when she was pregnant with him. She died soon after giving birth. His father enlisted close friends to raise Colin because he (the father) went on a suicide mission and destroyed a gateway portal of the demons.

The girl he jumps out of the plane to save was not his girlfriend at the time. She was a child that he saved from the demons who are, in fact, not demons but an alien species from another planet.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you go into a bit more detail about how this matches the description in the question? It might help OP remember whether this is indeed the series they're looking for.

Comment: Colin Rourk is an orphan whose mother was attacked by these demons when she was pregnant with him. She died soon after giving birth. His father enlisted close friends to raise Colin because he(The father) went on a suicide mission and destroyed a gateway portal of the demons. The girl he jumps out of the plane to save was not his girlfriend at the time. She was a child that he saved from the demons. Who are not demons but an alien species from another planet.

Comment: This is great info. you should edit your answer and add it there. Have you read the section in the help about how to write a good answer? You will find many great tips there about how to improve the text.

Comment: @BjornEriksson - With new users it's often better to show rather than tell. I've taken the liberty of editing OP's comment into their answer along with an inline link to the book series and a copy of the book cover.

Answer (score 2):

[Awaken](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004XMOOKS) looks like a YA story about a (probably adopted) magical teen named Colin and his sister (not girlfriend) that's currently available for free on Kindle, and is the first book in an extensive series.  Might that be what you're looking for?

Comment: Nope :(. The girl was definitely his girlfriend. They get together on book two i believe when she is ambushed by humans who are working together with the demons. He jumps out of a plane and kills them. Demons turn up after and he lets them go.

Comment: @Helpmefindthisbookthanks see, that's a detail that you need to include.  Also, if you're talkign about a girlfriend who doesn't show up until the second book, you're talking about the entire series, rather than a specific book in it.  You need to make that clearer.  Do you know how many books the series had?  Were they all based around the magic school?  This is important stuff for identifying the book you're talking about.

Comment: She is in the first book but they are not together they are just friends. There were four and the first book was about the school and some small missions, second he was the leader of the mages fighting the demons. Third he was leading them again on missions to the other dimensions and in a larger scale war. The fourth it about a side character who he thought was dead.